# fiddler not detecting android emulator http requests

Tags: android, web, android-emulator, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I am using android studio emulator api22(lollipop) and Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger (v4.6.2.30081)

I have followed [this](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-get-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler/) to make fiddler detect android http requests from browser. But **fiddler is not detecting requests** even after following all the steps. Fiddler detects my normal browser requests.

But **fiddler detects** when i access the **fiddler echo service** => (10.0.1.12:8888) via emulator

I have tried

=> restarting fiddler and emulator

=>changing proxy address of APN to my local ip address and port to fiddlers port(8888)

=>setting options of fiddler as mentioned in the [link](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-get-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler/).

=>turned off windows firewall for private networks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you can hit the echo service, that means the firewall and network configuration are okay. If you're not seeing other requests, it means the proxy settings on the client aren't properly pointed at the Fiddler IP/port.